# ezSql with multiple queries

Tags: php, ezsql

This is question, however:

In a PHP file, I am running an ezSql command (http://justinvincent.com/ezsql):

```
$_result = $db->get_var("CALL spcheck ('".$_var1."')");
```

then I have a if ($_result..

within that if, I have:

```
$_logInsert = $db->query("CALL splog1 ('".$_referrer."','".$_userAgent."','".$_ipAddress."','".$_countryCode."')");
```

However, I get the error:

**"Warning: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" when I try the second db call (first one runs fine)**

Is it not possible to have a globally defined $db and use it throughout the page multiple times?  Do I need to somehow `"cancel` the get_var after its executed so I can reuse it?

Comment: You can reuse the `$db` variable multiple times.

Comment: Thats what I was hoping.. Any idea why I'd be getting the above error?

Comment: It seems to be using the "CALL " in the get_var, etc.  When I change that to straight SQL statements, it runs fine.  No way to have a middle tier with the ezSQL libraries?

Comment: I have not used `CALL ... (...)` myself, inside or outside of the ezSQL library, so I have no idea why it would be failing. Maybe this would be better directed to Justin Vincent, the creator of the library - http://justinvincent.com/ezsql. As it's his baby, he'll have a better idea of any limitations/bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick Google and a peak under the hood of ezSQL.

In **ez_sql_mysql.php** (*or whatever name you may have given the file*) **Line 81** (*as at v2.11*)

Old code:

```
else if ( ! $this->dbh = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,true) )
```

New code:

```
else if ( ! $this->dbh = @mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,true,131074) )
```

Adapted from [Drupal Bugs - "Patch needed to execute MySQL stored procedures"](http://drupal.org/node/48195)

Comment: I actually had to change it to 131074, but it worked!  Many thanks for finding that!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated the answer for the next person dealing with this issue.